# machine learning for a rule

Tags: machine-learning, estimation

I have data in the following form , where x is an integer and r is 0 or 1.

I know that

- if $x < C$, then $r = 1$,
- if $x\geq C$, then $r= 0$.

How can I automatically estimate the value of $C$? Can I have any guarantees on the convergence?

There must be an easy way to solve this, I just cannot find out!

Answer (score 2):

If you have no idea to start with, you could start checking $1, 2, 4, \ldots 2^n$ until $r$ drops to zero.  Then you can use [the bisection method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method) of root finding to find the actual value.  Basically it takes the range that you know the transition is in, bisects it, and reduces the range appropriately.  Say $f(32)=1$ and $f(64)=0$.  Check $f(48)$.  If it is $1$, your range is now $(48,64]$.  If it is $0$, your range is now $(32,48]$.  Keep going this way.